# If something contains large amounts of cyclopentane and cyclohexane, what is it called?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, mixtures

If something contains large amounts of cyclopentane and cyclohexane, what is it called? I'd like to know what is the something as well. It's a chemistry olympiad question for this year. See [here](http://www.iuventa.sk/files/documents/2_olympiady/cho/51.%20ro%C4%8Dn%C3%ADk/%C3%BAlohy%20a%20rie%C5%A1enia/dom%C3%A1ce%20kolo/ch51dkcteul15.pdf), Question 3-g. Just let google translate it for you. I find some questions quite weird as well, but what can you do. Otherwise its pretty good.

Comment: Flammable. Is this seriously an Olympiad question? I highly doubt it has a specific name that is well accepted.

Comment: A barrel :D Merry christmas!

Comment: Which Olympiad was this in? National or international. I don't recall the question

Comment: Yes, this years house round of Chemistry Olympiade. http://www.iuventa.sk/files/documents/2_olympiady/cho/51.%20ro%C4%8Dn%C3%ADk/%C3%BAlohy%20a%20rie%C5%A1enia/dom%C3%A1ce%20kolo/ch51dkcteul15.pdf Question 3-g. Just let google translate it for you. I find some questions quite weird as well, but what can you do. Otherwise its pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely name would be [naphthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloalkane). It could also be called cycloalkanes.

Added:
Since the reference to the question is about the coal and oil production, the answer would be naphthenes. When the coal and oil were distilled, a layer (called naphthene) was removed which was found to contain mainly cyclopentane and cyclohexane.

I would complete the statement as:
If a **fraction of distillate** contains large amounts of cyclopentane and cyclohexane, it is called **naphthene**.

Comment: The answer should be much more concrete than this I assume. I need to replace the word something as well as figure out what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, I have a nice teacher so I can consult it with her without a problem. Fortunately enough, in the next rounds inspecific questions such as this one dont occur, they are more practical.

Comment: Also I suppose for better specification, I think it would be better like this: If a fraction of distillate from oil and coil contains large amounts of cyclopentane and cyclohexane, it is called naphthene. Surely not all fractions of distillates are called napthenes, right?